# Use case diagram "details" tab says "No Details"

Tags: use-case, visual-paradigm, use-case-diagram

I would like to add some preconditions to my use case but as soon as i enter my use case (description and all other tabs) the "Details" tab says "No Details". only one use case has an option to add preconditions and actually see the "Details" tab.
How can i make the "Details" tab visible?
thanks :)

Comment: I removed the UML tag since it's a pure tooling question and not really related to UML.

Answer (score 0):

The specification dialog is only for defining general information of the use case. Please right click on the use case and select **Open Use Case Details...** for entering the detail information such as pre/post-conditions, flow of events, discussion notes, etc...

Please note that this feature is supported in Standard Edition or above.

[image]